# ANTLR3C - how to get the text value of fall_through lexer token

Tags: antlr

I have similar problem as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705845/antlr-exception-handling-with-java). But I am using C version, antlr3c. It is not clear to me how to call getText(). I tried this:

```
FALL_THROUGH
  : .   { cerr << getText(); }
  ;
```

But the compiler says getText() not defined.

I then tried:

```
FALL_THROUGH
  : f=.   { cerr << $f->getText(); }
  ;
```

But it is also wrong, seems f is defined as an integer.

Any pointer how to get the text value?

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this. This would help:

```
FALL_THROUGH
  : f=.   { cerr << $f.text; }
  ;
```

Good luck!